# swift - how to modify property of object from another class?

Tags: ios, swift, object, viewcontroller

i added a second viewcontroller to my main viewcontroller. When my second viewcontroller want to modify the object of main viewcontroller its getting error.

first viewcontroller

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var uview:UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        uview = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(55, 175, 100, 100))
        uview.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        self.view.addSubview(uview)


        var sec = second()
        self.addChildViewController(sec)
        self.view.addSubview(sec.view)
        sec.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
    }
}
```

second viewcontroller

```
class second: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var button:UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(55, 55, 100, 100))
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        button.addTarget(self, action: "press", forControlEvents:UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(button)
    }

    func press(){
        var first:ViewController = ViewController()
        first.uview!.backgroundColor = UIColor.purpleColor()     
    }
}
```

Error message

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Thread 1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_I386_INVOP,subcode=0x0)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With this line `var first:ViewController = ViewController()` you are creating another instance of ViewController and not referencing to the view controller you want.
As you have a parent/child relationship, you can do

```
if let parent = self.parentViewController as ViewController {
    /*do something with parent variable*/
}
```

One more thing, your crash happens because your new instances had not load its view already (viewDidLoad) and your `uview` variable is not set.

Comment: if viewcontroller doesnt have parent/child relationship,i still want to change then property of object from another viewcontroller ,so what i want to do?

Comment: Create a custom variable of type ViewController in `second`. Then do `var sec = second();    sec.<#ViewController#> = self` in your first view controller.